# Read Rotated QR Codes

Tags: java, linux, swing, rotation, qr-code

I was given the taks to read QR Codes from scanned documents. However sometimes the sticker is not perfectly placed and the QR CODE is rotated like 30°, for example.

It is a **Java Swing** project. I'm using zxing to find the qrcode, but it has a hard time finding when it's rotated.

This project will run on a **Linux Ubuntu** environment, so any Linux command line magic, with ZBar for example, is also acceptable.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: The most simple and easiest way would be to rotate the whole picture for 360° with steps of 1 degree each. For each step check if a QR Code could be found if not proceed till you detected the code or finished the 360° rotation. You can also make the steps bigger to process images faster.

Comment: Thanks for the answer sir. That's the way we are going for. The problem is on big documents, like 120 pages. 
I posted the question with a hope for a simpler solution..